Physical Server Requirements for ffmpeg process
I need a hardware configuration for a server with the following requirements:
Backend using Nest.js
Frontend using Next.js
Microservice using Flask
The backend will utilize FFmpeg processes to stream and record video without audio from Hikvision IP cameras with the following parameters:

Model:  Hyvision ds-2cd1023g0e-i }
Codec: H.265+
Maximum bitrate: 4096 Kbps
Resolution: 1920x1080p at 30fps
We will start with 5 cameras but plan to scale up to 20 cameras.


Hi, welcome to Hardware Recs! Can you clarify what specifically you mean by processing, streaming, and recording (maybe provide a sample pipeline?) Also, what's your budget? Are you looking for rack-mount, some other form factor, or no preference? Are you paying for power? If so, how much?

In your case, you need a server with good high-bandwidth network cards and high bandwidth on the motherboard along with the processor/s. You mentioned the requirement for a 4 Mb/s LAN, I don't know if there are server motherboards with 10 Mb/s or 2.5 Mb/s network cards, and you need at least 2 of them configured in different subnets. This involves replacing switches and connecting cables compatible with 10Mb/s or 2.5Mb/s bandwidth. The above-mentioned IP cameras use 10/100 Mb network cards. I won't say anything about the performance of the servers themselves, I'll let the experts comment...
